# Zabbix мониторинг GeoServer через интерфейс JMX

Tags: windows, java, linux

Здравствуйте!
С ХэшКод меня направили сюда, поэтому сильно не пинайте за повторение вопроса...

Стоит задача разворачивания Zabbix для мониторинга GeoServer-а.
Если с установкой и настройкой Zabbix для мониторинга с помощью Zabbix аггента проблем не возникло, то как заставить работать JMX мониторинг - большая загадка.

Была установлена версия 2.0.4 поддерживающая на стороне сервера (как я это понял) JMX без дополнительного ПО, как это было раньше...
Пусть так, но заставить Zabbix собирать данные JMX не получается.

Ладно GeoServer, хотя бы какое-нибудь Java-приложение замониторить...

Кто сталкивался, или у кого есть советы - прошу высказаться...

PS: за основу брал документацию Zabbix: [Мониторинг JMX](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/ru/2.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring)

PS2: вопрос более подробно задан на Zabbix на случай если ответят быстрее, или в этом вопросе недостаточно информации:
[Zabbix и проблемы конфигуририрования JMX](https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=42757)

PS3: Забыл уточнить - данные JMX нужно брать с Windows машины (по крайней мере, на данный момент).

Answer (score 1):

В своих проектах мы тоже используем мониторинг java приложения посредством jmx. И делали мы его еще тогда когда zabbix не содержал в себе громкие слова  c jmx аббревиатурой.В итоге пришлось воспользоваться такой сущностью как UserParameter.

В конфигах zabbix agent писали консольный jmxclient

```
UserParameter=java.USSDInCountSuccess,java -jar /home/project/cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - localhost:3099 ru.company.project.ussd:name=ussd MOSuccessCount
```

Который в итоге возвращал произвольный параметр, который уже кормили в zabbix. И мониторили его. Конечно это не удобно с точки зрения маштабирования, так как такой параметр не содержится по дефолту и просто так его не включить в какой либо tamplate. Но оно работает.

Comment: Rажется я в попыхах забыл уточнить, что данные нужно получить не из linux, а window...  Извините, сейчас поправлю вопрос...Но все равно спасибо за ответ - возьму на заметку,и попробую под windows сделать аналогично, может получится))

Comment: Запускайте на линупсе, просто localhost:3099 замените на нужный вам параметр подключения. И не забудьте включить jmx  в самой jvm.